# Creating a timer and cannot restart it

Tags: java, timer

I've created GUI timer, it runs exactly how I wanted it to. I have a stop and pause button, when I stop or pause the timer and restart a new one I get Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled

I'm unsure what I'm suppose to do I've read you cant reuse tasks, but I have no clue to solve this. Can someone PLEASE help me out I'm going crazy over this, I always seem to fix one problem but another one pops up.

Heres part of my code which does the countdown

```
private  TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
@Override
public void run(){
    if (countdown()) {
        if(minutes < 9 && seconds < 9)
        timerOutput.setText("0"+minutes + ": 0" + seconds);
        else if(minutes < 9)
        timerOutput.setText("0"+minutes + ":" + seconds);
        else if(seconds < 9)
        timerOutput.setText(minutes + ": 0" + seconds);

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Finish!");
        timerOutput.setText("Time is up!");
        timer.cancel();
        startBut.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

};

```
private boolean countdown(){
    seconds --;
    if (seconds < 0){
        minutes--;
        seconds = 59;

        if (minutes == -1){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `TimerTask`s aren't designed to be reused. The best you can do is create a new `TimerTask` every time you're going to reschedule it.

Comment: What would be the best way to do that

Comment: Depends on how your class is organized, but simply create a new one every time you reschedule it. If it would involve repeating parts of your code, make the code inside the `run` method a separate method and call it inside the `run` method to avoid repeating.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't simply restart a `Timer`, you could create a `Timer` wrapper class which would act exactly like a Timer but allow a simple restart method that would instantiate a new `Timer` in the background. For example;

```
public class RestartableTimer{

    private Timer timer;
    private long delay, period;

    public RestartableTimer(){
        timer = new Timer();
    }  

    public void scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period){
        this.delay = delay;
        this.period = period;
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period);
    }

    public void restart(TimerTask task){
        timer.cancel();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period);
    } 
}
```

A fair warning, this would not allow for polymorphism. You couldn't for example store a `RestartableTimer` in a `Timer` reference. You will also still need to instantiate a new `TimerTask` when you restart. If you wanted (and you knew you would only be reusing the same `TimerTask`), you could declare a custom and private embedded class in the above and let the wrapper class handle the creation of the new `TimerTask`. Alternatively you could have the class methods take a `TimerTaskFactory` which would implement an Interface which required a method that returned a `TimerTask`.

Below, an example of using the above class;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Running");
        }};
    RestartableTimer rt = new RestartableTimer();
    System.out.println("Timer starting with one task");
    rt.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("Timer restarting with another task");
    rt.restart(new TimerTask(){
        int count = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(count>4) {
                System.out.println("Done");
                this.cancel();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Running 2");
                count++;
            }
        }});
}
```